# Evaluating $\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-\cdots}}}}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, radicals, nested-radicals

I was wondering if it was possible to evaluate

> $$\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-\cdots}}}}}}}$$

I let the expression equal $x>0$ and wrote $$x=\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-x}}$$ However, there is not just one value $x$ can take; $x=2$ or $x=3$.

How do I find out which one it is, or does this infinite-nested radical converge at all? Perhaps it merely oscillates between $2$ and $3$, but I am not entirely sure. Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

---

The ellipsis means "and so on". It measures the following: $$\sqrt{9-5}$$ $$\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5}}}$$ $$\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5}}}}}$$ $$\vdots$$

Incidentally, I did not refuse to clarify the meaning. I am only active on Math.SE for so long. Whatever requests that occur can only be followed up the moment I am active, can see them and have time to act.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen now that I have actually seen your comments, I think the real question *is* about why there is ambiguity. I mean, both the sequences you have defined recursively are the same, but tend toward different limits, which is not entirely clear to me. Unless, they are not the same?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I redacted my vote to close.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no worries :)

Comment: Anyway, all the numbers of this sequence are equal to $2$, so that is also the limit :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen but doesn't the numbers of the sequence in my post and a sequence where it's equal to $3$... aren't they both the same numbers, just expressed in different sequences?

Comment: No, they aren't. One might hope that it wouldn't matter. Like with the sequences of decimals when
$$0.27,\ 0.2727,\ 0.272727,\ 0.27272727,\ldots$$
and
$$0.2,\ 0.272,\ 0.27272,\ 0.2727272,\ldots,$$
where it doesn't matter. Both sequences converge to $3/11$. The key being that their difference rapidly tends to zero. What we see here is more like the difference between
$$1,\ 1-1+1,\ 1-1+1-1+1,\ldots$$
and
$$1-1,\ 1-1+1-1,\ 1-1+1-1+1-1,\ldots,$$
with the former sequence being constant $1$ and the latter constant $0$, leaving the meaning of
$$1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1\cdots$$ undefined.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that was a beautiful example. Thank you very much for your help. Muchly appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: (reposting a part of a deleted comment of mine). The sequence
$$\sqrt{9},\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt9}}, \sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt9}}}},\ldots$$
with the added stuff ending at a $9$, is a constant sequence of $3$s. On the other hand, if we always end at a $5$, the sequence consists of $2$s only. And if we end at a $3$, the sequence converges towards $2$. This is in line with both the answers. This interpretation is the only way to get $3$ as the answer, but it does highlight the ambiguity.

Answer (score 8):

Infinitely nested radicals may not make sense. The usual way to define this expression is as $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$, where $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{9 - 5\sqrt{3 - a_n}}$. The problem here is that we have no initial point specified. Choosing $a_0 = 2$ or $a_0 = 3$ will produce two different limits, so the nested radical is not well-defined.

Comment: @AnthonyLahmann's answer contradicts yours. Unfortunately for you, I am leaning towards their answer instead. :/

Comment: Actually, I don't know. Who am I supposed to believe? lol

Comment: @MrPie Ultimately, it's a difference in convention. It's like pointing out that $0^0$ is undefined; it is true, but in certain situations, it makes sense to invent your own convention and say it's $1$. You can ignore unstable fixed points of $f(x) = \sqrt{9 - 5\sqrt{3 - x}}$ if it helps you get where you need to go, but just don't lose sight of the fact that you're using a non-standard convention for nested radicals.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The three dots just means "and so on", with $(9-5, 3), (9-5, 3)$ and etc.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I may need to work on my rigour. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is $2$. While $3$ is also a fixed point, it is unstable because if we let $x=3-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$, and iterate $x\leftarrow \sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-x}}$, it will diverge away from $3$.

[image: Graph of <span class=]$\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-x}}$">

If you look at the graph, you will find that the slope approaches $\infty$ as $x\to 3$. The derivative of $\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-x}}$ is $\frac5{4\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-x}}\sqrt{3-x}}$. When $x\to 3$, the $\sqrt{3-x}$ in the denominator will approach $0$, which means the derivative approaches $\infty$ as $x\to 3$. Therefore, the fixed point is unstable and will very quickly diverge away from $3$. Plugging $2$ into the equation gives $\frac58$, which is less than $1$. Therefore, the fixed point is stable.

**In conclusion:**

> $$\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-\cdots}}}}}}}=2$$

Comment: Yes! I needed it to be $2$. Thank you so much!

Comment: If this be true, it means the following formula is true: $$\begin{align}\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 3 &= \sqrt{9+4\sqrt{1+\sqrt{7+3\sqrt{5+\sqrt{7+3\sqrt{5+\sqrt{7+\cdots}}}}}}} \\ &- \sqrt{7+4\sqrt{1+\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-5\sqrt{3-\sqrt{9-\cdots}}}}}}}\end{align}$$ The symmetries allign :)